# Rewrite hashbang in URL

Tags: javascript

I've seen many questions relating to URL redirects, but I can't work out how to do the following:

Current URL:
/listings/any-subdirectory/#comment-4

Desired URL:
/listings/the-same-subdirectory/#review-4

I know I can grab the ID with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]*)$
```

Although I'm not quite sure how to formulate the RewriteRule.

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

It seems that if I use the following Regex expression
    `#(.+-)`
...and then replace it with
    `#review-`

...I can get the proper URL format, at least using [this Regex tester](http://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html).

But I'm not sure how to put this into practice via Javascript (since this apparently can't be done in the .htaccess file since it's a URL fragment).

Comment: You cant redirect fregments using htaccess as # is not sent to the server. You need to do a client side redirection using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^\/listings\/[^\/]+\//.test(location.pathname) &&
    /^#comment-/.test(location.hash) &&
    location.replace(location.href.replace(/#[^-]+/, '#review'));
```

The first `replace` is [`Location.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) but the second is only a [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/String/replace).

Comment: Oooh, this looks nice! This wouldn't be the whole script though, right? It seems like it's the bulk of what I need, but I'm not sure of the full context.

Comment: @Tim That's it. Chuck it in a `<script>` tag, early in the head, so it doesn't waste time loading the page only to redirect.

Comment: You're my hero! Thank you very much for your time.